# ADD Email Signature with gmail api using .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, gmail

Can anyone tell me how can I update /add /modify email signature using dot net MVC with Gmail API? I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfeKF1zgwj0 but I didn't find any way for doing it in .net MVC.

Comment: See if following helps.  Code uses a certificate and once certificate is loaded the SMTP email is automatically signed : https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=9

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Hi ! Did you already had a previous email signature? Are you using [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) to send these emails ? By email signature do you refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_block)?

Comment: wisestamp.com i need this site features to include in my site